# Time delay for Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, time

I am trying to use the following code:

```
m_WebView_Search.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(m_WebView_Search.hasFocus()){
                Animation mWSE = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.mWSE);
                m_WebView_Search.startAnimation(mWSE);
            }
        }
    });
```

But only to run after waiting 800ms. So pretty much run the statement but way 800ms before doing it. Is this possible? And if so how can I implant this into the following code. As well if I could make it a variable that would be better cause I would have more instalments of this 800ms Delay.
sorry for the little information I really don't know what to post for this issue.

The initial corner radius is 100 each 
[image: This is the image of the cutoff characters swell as the stretched corners[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCrIn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this .

**1.Use `View` 's `public boolean postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)`**

```
int POST_DELAY_TIME = 2000;
m_WebView_Search.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_WebView_Search.startAnimation(mWSE);
    }
}, POST_DELAY_TIME);
```

**2.Use `Handler` 's `public final boolean postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_WebView_Search.startAnimation(mWSE);
    }
}, POST_DELAY_TIME);
```

Comment: Good luck to you .@EquiWare

Comment: I have a new issue if you are willing to help

Comment: You can describe about it .

Comment: When the animation is done the corner radius of the background is stretch, The text size is stretched, as well as the first 4characters you type are blocked form view

Comment: Sorry， I've been thinking for a while, and I didn't think of a good way to do it.@EquiWare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163370/discussion-between-equiware-and-keliuyue).

Comment: is there another way to do this or no or avoid this

Comment: Could you show some picture about it ? I did not understand about it .And I will check for you . Hope  that I can help you .

Comment: add the photos for showing with initial corner radius

Comment: You can google for the animation .And do something with the shape .

Comment: im not following what you mean